# From GoogleYolo (Google Smart Lock), what does "Invalid audience" mean?

Tags: google-api, google-signin, google-identity-toolkit, google-identity, google-smartlockpasswords

The error/warning message (written by obfuscated code from [https://www.gstatic.com/*/mss/boq-identity/*/js/k=boq-identity.IdentityYoloWebModuleset.en.5jYiE0Kzqd0.O/m=yolo_frame_library/rt=j/d=1/rs=AOaEmlHvGDn8UcjjSaG2zLiaoxdbMowW7g](https://www.gstatic.com/_/mss/boq-identity/_/js/k=boq-identity.IdentityYoloWebModuleset.en.5jYiE0Kzqd0.O/m=yolo_frame_library/rt=j/d=1/rs=AOaEmlHvGDn8UcjjSaG2zLiaoxdbMowW7g) to the console, Chrome Version 65.0.3325.162) is, "Invalid audience. Please use the Google Cloud console (https://console.developers.google.com), and create a valid OAuth2 web client."

I was following https://developers.google.com/identity/one-tap/web/get-started -- does anyone know if a single-archive fully-complete example exists anywhere?  (I looked.)

My code goes as follows, and I did set https://localhost:8000 and a personal website with https as allowed origins for the client ID in question, which are where I'm testing this.

```
<html>
 <head>
    <script src="https://smartlock.google.com/client"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
   <script>
const clientID = "...";
const authUri = "https://accounts.google.com";

window.onGoogleYoloLoad = (googleyolo) =>
    {
    const retrievePromise = googleyolo.retrieve(
        {
        supportedAuthMethods: [ authUri ],
        supportedIdTokenProviders: [ { uri: authUri, clientId: clientID } ]
        });
    }
  </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Moreover, I tested similar code except with `googleyolo.hint` then `googleyolo.retrieve` and the other way around. Both ways, each time I refreshed the page, it was as if I have never visited before -- and that's whether or not I was logged in to Google in Chrome.  So after the hint completes, what needs done to save or store that status?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find some working examples located here -

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/579564/JavaScript-oAuth

https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/sign-in

I setup a test script using the examples from the CodeProject link, and just commented out the pieces I did not need.

```
<div class="loginDiv">
    <div id="googlelogin">Google</div>
</div>
<div style="clear:both;" id="userinfo"></div>
```

var clientId = '.....';

var scopes = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me';

Enjoy!

Comment: Thank you; this works as it should, though it doesn't use the new authentication approach, which is what I'm seeking to debug.  https://developers.google.com/identity/one-tap/web/get-started

Comment: How about this one?

https://github.com/hemantjadon/yolo-auth/blob/master/yolo-auth.html

Comment: Thank you; I was able to pull out useful bits and pieces from this one.